# How can I build list from the values of a dictionary?

Tags: arrays, ansible, ldap

I have a list of AD users and trying to create a distinguishedName-list

```
vars:
  admin_users: "user1;user2"
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
    admin: "{{ admin_users.split(';') }}"

  - name: Search account
    community.general.ldap_search:
    <...>
    loop: "{{ admin }}"
    register: ldap_result

  - name: Build DN-array
    set_fact:
      group: "{{ group | default([]) }} +  {{ item.value | json_query(query) }}"
    with_dict: "{{ ldap_result.results }}"
    when: item.key == 'results'
    vars:
      query: "[*].distinguishedName"

  - debug:
    var: "{{ group }}"
```

And get

```
"<class 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

Also tried

```
group: "{{ group | default([]) }} + [ {{ item.value | json_query(query) }} ]"
group: "{{ group | default([]) }} + {{ [ item.value | json_query(query) ] }}"
```

get same message

```
"<class 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

and

```
group: "{{ group | default([]) }} + [ '{{ item.value | json_query(query) }}' ]"
```

Then I get the error

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected
token ',', got 'CN'. String: {{[] + [ '['CN=***']' ] + [ '['CN=***']' ]}}"}
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that's right, I just needed to use a construction like this

```
    <...>
    group: "{{ group | default([]) }} + [ {{ item.value | json_query(query) }} ]"
    <...>
    - debug: msg="{{ group }}"
```

not this

```
- debug:
    var: "{{ group_list_two }}"
```

correct output

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "CN=***"
        ],
        [
            "CN=***"
        ]
    ]
}
```